# time series: resample from hour to quarter. Last rows missing

Tags: datetime, pandas, resampling

**Problem:**
I have a list of 4 rows (for each hour) with values which are datetime indexed. Now I want to have 16 (4*4) rows with each value copied 3 times and filled in Forward.

**My Question:** How can I tell Pandas/Python to write the last three lines? 
[Thats what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mm6B.png)

**My try:**

## create dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'A' : [4,5,6,7], 'B' : [10,20,30,40],'C' : [100,50,-30,-50]})
```

## create date

```
date_60min = pd.date_range(
'1/1/2013', periods=4, freq='60min', tz='Europe/Berlin')
```

## add date

```
df['Date'] = date_60min
```

## set date to index

```
df_date = df.set_index('Date')
```

## show df_date

```
df_date
```

## Variation 1 with resmaple

```
df_resample15min = df_date.resample(
'15Min',fill_method='ffill', label='left', closed='right')
df_resample15min
```

## Variation 2 with asfreq

```
df_asfreq15min = df_date.asfreq('15Min', method='pad')
df_asfreq15min
```

Comment: Does it work if you pass param to `resample` `closed='right'`?

Comment: Sorry this seems to work for me, can you post reproducable code, your numpy and pandas version, thanks

Comment: HI EdChum =) closed 'right' does not work for me. Maybe I did something wrong with the datetime index?